# Python + SQLite query to find entries that sit in a specified time slot

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to store a row in an SQLite 3 table for each booking in my diary.

Each row will have a 'start time' and a 'end time'.

Does any one know how I can query the table for an event at a given time?

E.g. Return any rows that happen at say 10:30am

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite3 doesn't have a datetime type, though it does have [date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Typically you store dates and times in your database in something like ISO 8601 format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. Then datetimes sort lexicographically into time order.

With your datetimes stored this way, you simply use text comparisons such as

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tbl.start = '2009-02-01 10:30:00'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE '2009-02-01 10:30:00' BETWEEN tbl.start AND tbl.end;
```

Comment: Ok, I looked at the link on sqlite site, but I am unclear how to say if the time i am searching for is between startime and endtime. 
Can you help?